# Ajax post to MVC controller List<T> properties correct count but null

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

In MVC using Telerik MultiSelect control I am posting back to the controller via ajax. My data is correct but I am missing some connection on how to get the POST action to interpret the ajax data parameter as it is always the correct number of elements but they are null.

My model:

```
public class SeeAlso
{
    public List<SubCategories> SelectedCategories { get; set; }
    public List<SubCategories> AvailableCategories { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public async Task<ActionResult> SeeAlso_Update(SeeAlso data)
{
   if (data != null && ModelState.IsValid)
   {...}
}
```

My cshtml:

```
<h2>See Also</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<label for="required">Selected</label>
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()
  .Name("SeeAlso")
  .Placeholder("Selected Categories...")
  .BindTo(Model.AvailableCategories.Select(x => x.SubCategoryName).ToList())
  .Value(Model.SelectedCategories.Select(c => c.SubCategoryName).ToArray())
  .Events(e => { e.Change("onChange"); })
)
}

<script type="text/javascript">
function onChange()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Admin/SeeAlso/SeeAlso_Update",
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",

        data: JSON.stringify({ SelectedCategories: $("#SeeAlso").data("kendoMultiSelect").dataItems() })

    });

}

</script>
```

And when I post is always gets the count right but the value is null.

[image]

As requesteed here is the json which I know is close but I don't know how to get the parent SeeAlso container represented.

```
{"SelectedCategories":["Cat1","Cat2"]}
```

Comment: Please do a console.log on the data you're passing to the server and check how different is the structure of the data going from the client-side to the server-side to match the class SubCategories in order to be received successfully.

Comment: From the code it looks like you're setting a property SubCategoryName on the Kendo user control, and dataItems() function is returning an array of SubCategoryName as strings I think, so as a string array is passed to the server you see the count to be correct but the items are null, you need to pass an array of objects having the SubCategoryName property in order for the mapping to happen to your SubCategories class.

Comment: You cannot bind a `<select multiple>` to a collection of complex objects. The property you bind to needs to be `IEnumerable<string> SelectedCategories` not `IEnumerable<SubCategories>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot bind a `<select multiple>` to a collection of complex objects (it posts back only and array of the values of the selected options) so the property you need to bind to needs to be `IEnumerable<string>` (assuming `SubCategoryName` is typeof `string`). You view model needs to be

```
public class SeeAlso
{
    public IEnumerable<string> SelectedCategories { get; set; }
    public List<SubCategories> AvailableCategories { get; set; }
}
```

To submit the model using ajax, you can simply serialize the form

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Admin/SeeAlso/SeeAlso_Update",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: $('form').serialize();
});
```

which will correctly bind to

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SeeAlso_Update(SeeAlso model)
```

and `model.SelectedCategories` will be an array of the selected option values.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the JSON mapping in your SubCategories class doesn't quite match what is getting passed up.  If you temporarily change your *data* variable to type of *object* and then step through it, you should see an anonymous type that will show you what is really getting passed. Or you can look in the Network tab of Developer Tools in Chrome and see the actual JSON that's getting posted--it will probably have some subtle difference.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I needed a hybrid of answers, but in my lack of knowledge I didn't make the question very clear. @Stephen Muecke was most helpful and I have accepted his answer. Here is how I ultimately got everything working.

Model:

```
public class SeeAlso
{
    public List<int> SelectedCategories { get; set; }
    public List<SubCategories> AvailableCategories { get; set; }
}

public class SubCategories
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string SubCategoryName { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

}
```

cshtml:

```
<div>
<h2>See Also</h2>

<label for="required">Selected</label>

@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(m => m.SelectedCategories)
        .Placeholder("Selected Categories...")
        .DataTextField("SubCategoryName")
        .DataValueField("Id")
        .BindTo(Model.AvailableCategories)
        )

<br/>
<button type="submit" name="saveButton" id="saveButton">Save</button>
<br/>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#saveButton").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Admin/SeeAlso/Update",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify({ SelectedCategories: $("#SelectedCategories").data("kendoMultiSelect").dataItems() })
    })
});
</script>
```

Controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("Admin/SeeAlso")]
public class SeeAlsoController : Controller
{

   [HttpPost]
   [Route("Update")]
   public async Task<ActionResult> SeeAlso_Update(List<SubCategories> SelectedCategories)
   {
        if (SelectedCategories != null && ModelState.IsValid)
        { ... }
        return Json(ModelState.ToDataSourceResult());
   }
}
```